# Where to disable {position: relative;} from inline?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am currently working with Photolite template with Wordpress, and the slider cannot display correctly as the part of the background unless I unchecked `{position: relative;}` which is the red box in the figure.

I understand that `style.css:240` means the `240th` line of the file `style.css` but the line I am intending to modify is `inline:1`. My question is where I should go to disable this `{position: relative;}`.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are using the developer tools to disable it. These changes cannot be carried over to other users. There may also be a script that adds that `CSS` property inline

Comment: Just click the "inline:1" link and you will see

Comment: Yes, I use developer tools to identify the issue, but i have no idea to disble this on my wrodpress setting, when i click inline:1 it bring me to embedded stylesheet #17, i have not idea where it located.

Comment: @FredericLiu That's the 17th stylesheet in the document. Just go find it.

Comment: @Oriol which document? the style.css locate at wp-content/themes/phototheme/css/style.css another folder css only have nivo-slider.css and theme-reponsive.css I have no more .css under the theme folder

Comment: Did you read SLaks answer? "*inline means a <style> tag somewhere directly in the HTML*". It's in the HTML, not in the theme folder. If you don't find it in the HTML source, then probably a script created it. We can't know without a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify the header.php as

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?>
<div class="header" style="position: absolute">
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="header">
<?php } ?>
```

which resolved my issue.

Comment: Please, include the code sample inside your answer. Also, you should avoid inline style as it will bite you back. You're just postponing problems. And, the best thanks on SO are upvotes!

Answer (score 2):

`inline` means a `<style>` tag somewhere directly in the HTML (as opposed to an external CSS file).

You need to find that tag and figure out what's creating it.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah not necessarily, it could be in the body as well. While HTML 4 specify that it must be in the head, most browsers will support `style` in the body.

Answer (score 0):

*Just to add to the correct [SLaks's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38728024/1218980)*

Often, with wordpress, the *custom css* section in the admin of your theme is stored in the database and a script renders it inside a `<style>` tag in the head.

So it's probably not a hardcoded `<style>` tag, but a generated one.